# Work folders and domain guest

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, file-sharing

I have setup Workfolders on my Windows Server 2012 R2. This is all working fine, however I want to be able to use my domain guest user on my domain computers. 
This is not possible according to [this article on technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/de8906cf-1a04-4967-8a77-9b147ee5c3ce/work-folders-client-setup-errors-no-prompt-for-ad-credentials-lockscreen-policies-not-applied?forum=winservergen). I wonder if there is a solutions to enable my client computers to use the domain guest user.

The error I am getting on my (non-domain joined) computers is the following, I am not prompted for a username or password either:

`Partnership type: User Data; Error: (0x80c80037)  You’re not set up on the server. Email your organization’s tech support and ask them if they can give you access to Work Folders.`

The error disappears when I disable my guest account.

Comment: The correct (english) error for `0x80c80037` is _No sync share is configured for the user. User: **UserName**; Error code: (0x80c80037) You’re not set up on the server. Email your organization’s tech support and ask them if they can give you access to Work Folders._

Comment: Have you tried logging in as `domain\Guest`

Comment: There is no option to input credentials in workfolders when the guest user is enabled.